# Limit User input and remove special character in a DataGridView Cell

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a DataGridView with one `DataGridTextBoxColumn`. It is a bound to a datasource. The user can enter values such as `-$12,345,678.90` (formatting is applied when tabbing out).

So what I am trying to achieve is when a user types a value like this:  `-$12,345,678.90`, in my `DataGridTextBoxColumn`, I need to check the number's length, allowing a maximum length, which in my example is `10` (excluding `- $ , .`).

If the input number reaches a length of `10`, I need to prevent the user from entering more numbers.

In the `KeyDown` event handler, I tried to use Regular Expression to remove the `- $ , .` symbols from whatever the user entered in the Cell, to find the length of the input and check whether it exceeded the maximum allowed length (e.g., `10`). Like this:

```
//length = length value returned after performing Regex replacement with empty
If length = 10 Then
   Handled = True
End if
```

I also set my `DataGridTextBoxColumn` max length to 15 (including `$ - . ,`) while setting up the Grid.

The problem with this approach is that when a user tries to update a number, for example changing `$12,345,678.90` to `$22,345,678.90`, it will treat it as a new input, so it will fail and not allow the user to update a number.

I also tried some other events such as `CellEndEdit`, `CellValueChanged` but these events are only firing when I tab out or the focus is moved from the Cell.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 3):

You can handle the [EditingControlShowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing) event and set the Text of the Edit Control (it's a TextBox) to the actual value: it should be of Type `Decimal`.
The User can then edit the value without any formatting getting in the way.

In the [CellEndEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit) event handler, check whether the Value set falls within the allowed range and, in case it doesn't, revert back the edit calling [CancelEdit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.canceledit) and set the [Cell.ErrorText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.errortext) to provide a visual clue that something went wrong. Or show a MessageBox, or whatever fits.

To prevent exceptions in case the User enters an invalid Decimal value, the [CellParsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing) handler rejects and reset the previous value if [Decimal.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse) doesn't validate the input. It also shows a notification that includes the wrong input.

---

If you haven't defined the Column's `ValueType` and a `Format` in its DefaultCellStyle, do this right after you have set the `[DataGridView].DataSource`:
(replace `ColumnName` with the actual name of the Column)

```
DataGridView1.Columns("ColumnName").ValueType = GetType(Decimal)
DataGridView1.Columns("ColumnName").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C" ' Or "C2"
```

**Note**:
Cell value rollback assumes that the DataGridView source of data supports notifications (e.g., a DataTable or a `BindingList(Of [class])` where `[class]` implements `INotifyPropertyChange`).

---

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox AndAlso dgv.CurrentCell.ValueType = GetType(Decimal) Then
        e.Control.Text = CDec(dgv.CurrentCell.Value).ToString()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellParsing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellParsing
    If e.DesiredType IsNot GetType(Decimal) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value?.ToString()) Then Return
    Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim cell = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)

    If Not Decimal.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), Nothing) Then
        e.Value = cell.Value
        e.ParsingApplied = True
        cell.ErrorText = $"Invalid Value: {e.Value}"
    Else
        cell.ErrorText = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    If dgv.Columns("ColumnName").Index = e.ColumnIndex Then
        Dim cell = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
        Dim value = CDec(cell.Value)
        If value > 9999999999D OrElse value < -9999999999D Then
            dgv.CancelEdit()
            cell.ErrorText = "Value outside range"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jimi thanks for your guidance, i will check and will update here the result

Comment: Hi Jimi how do i restrict the user from entering two decimal point in that value. Right now i can enter two decimal dots in between. Also in my case i need to check the value length. So in that case how will i use cell value to gets its count?

Comment: I added a parser to validate the input: it will reject values that don't pass validation, reverting the value back to the previous state and showing the notification. -- You don't need to check *the length of the input*, we're working with floating point values here, the maximum and minimum values are already verified in the `CellEndEdit` handler: `If value > 9999999999D OrElse value < -9999999999D Then ...` --  You need to make sure that the `ValueType` of the data source and the DGV Column is `Decimal`. **For sure not `String`**.